# TypeError: an integer is required on my python script

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin

I'm doing a python code that:

- Take data from an API
- parse the data
- build a query and send it to my PGadmin database

Here's my code:

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json
import datetime
import os
import psycopg2
from urlparse import urlparse


try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='tp_1' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='senha'")
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, ex:
    print 'I am unable to connect the database: ' + str(ex)

cur = conn.cursor()
url = "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/day-summary/2013/6/20/"

moeda = url.split('/')[4]

response = requests.get(url)

print("---------------------")
data = response.text
print(data)
print("---------------------")

parsed = json.loads(data)

opening = parsed["opening"]
closing = parsed["closing"]
lowest = parsed["lowest"]
highest = parsed["highest"]
volume = parsed["volume"]
quantity = parsed["quantity"]
amount = parsed["amount"]
avg_price = parsed["avg_price"]
date = parsed["date"]

print(opening)
print(closing)
print(lowest)
print(highest)
print(volume)
print(quantity)
print(amount)
print(avg_price)
print(date)

SQL = "INSERT INTO day_summary (id_day, data_day, opening, closing, lowest, highest ,volume,quantity, amount, avg_price )  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
data = (1,datetime.date(date), opening, closing, lowest, highest, volume, quantity, amount, avg_price)
cur.execute(SQL, data)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

This is the outputs from my prints:

```
---------------------
{"date": "2013-06-20", "opening": 262.99999, "closing": 269.0, "lowest": 260.00002, "highest": 269.0, "volume": 7253.13363568, "quantity": 27.11390588, "amount": 28, "avg_price": 267.50604165}
---------------------
262.99999
269.0
260.00002
269.0
7253.13363568
27.11390588
28
267.50604165
2013-06-20
```

And here's my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dados_api_day.py", line 56, in <module>
    data = (1,datetime.date(date), opening, closing, lowest, highest, volume, quantity, amount, avg_price)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I am not being able to solve the problem. I hope I could make it clear enough, so you can help me!
Thanks!

Comment: The amazing thing is that you don't have to. Python gives you a traceback that shows exactly what line threw the error and why. Please include it in your question as an edit.

Comment: Please, for a better understanding of your issue, include the stack trace that python generates.

Comment: Completly forgot to put it the post, there it is

Comment: What did it print, when you printed all the variables? Were they all valid integers? Are you sure they are all Ints?

Comment: Hi Biclops! I edited the post so you can see the outputs. If they're valid integers or no, i'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. It was caused by the date.
In fact, when I parse the data from the URL, the date variable is UNICODE.
What you need to do is convert it by doing:

```
your_new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_that_you_want_to_convert, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Hope it will help!